# How do you write a formula for Compound Interest when you are also depositing a set amount each time it compounds?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

My cousin plays this game called Alien Shooter and he asked me this and I couldn't figure it out. So basically you get $10$ coins right off the bat, even if you die in the first round. After every round you beat you get an additional $10$ coins and the total value also increases by $10\%$. When I tested it I got values like this (round $0$ is dying on the first round):

```
Round  0  1  2  3  4  5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
Coins 10 22 36 52 70 90 112 136 162 190 220 252 286 322 360 400 etc.
```

I thought this would be pretty simple but for some reason I can't figure out what the formula would be.

Comment: In finance, it is called an ordinary annuity. You can see it [here](https://www.investopedia.com/retirement/calculating-present-and-future-value-of-annuities/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the recurrence $x_{n+1} =\frac{11}{10}(x_{n} +10)$ is solid (it matches the description of the problem), it doesn't take into account round-ups.

That being said, the given values don't behave like an exponential, even with some rounding. The first twelve values behave just like a quadratic:
$$f(n) =n^2 +11n +10 =(n+10)(n+1).$$
I'm prone to believe the OP values at $n=14$ and $n=15$ where meant to be $100$ units greater.
\begin{array}{l|rr}
n        & 0& 1& 2& 3& 4& 5&  6&  7&  8&  9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15\\ \hline
\text{OP}&10&22&36&52&70&90&112&136&162&190&220&252&284&320&258&298\\
f(n)     &10&22&36&52&70&90&112&136&162&190&220&252&286&322&360&400\\
\text{diff.}&&&&&&&&&&&&&+2&+2&102&102
\end{array}

Comment: Yeah you're right. I really messed up the values. Sorry about that. What you gave is perfect, thank you.

Comment: Cool! You are welcome. If the problem is solved, please consider accepting and upvoting this answer just to let people know.

Comment: Can you explain why though? Why does this behave quadratically and not exponentially?

Comment: The game programmers just decided to use the quadratic rather than the exponential, despite the way the score is described to increase. They may have goofed up, or didn't care, or (most likely) decided that an exponential function for the score is way more complicated, since exponentials are prone to grow dramatically after a certain point: if the game is meant to be played for several rounds, it would be very hard to keep track of the score using the finite arithmetic of computers (or the teeny tiny space on the screen where the score might be displayed.)

Comment: \begin{array}{c|cc} n& 10& 25& 50& 75& 100& 125& 150\\ \hline {1.1}^n& 2.5& 10.8& 117.4& \approx 1.3\times {10}^3& \approx 1.4\times {10}^4& \approx 1.5\times {10}^5& \approx 1.6\times {10}^6 \end{array}
Then, just look at the function $f(n)=n^2+11n+10=(n+10)(n+1)$. It's nice, simple, doesn't increase overwhelmingly on the long run, and always outputs integers. And for the values you provided, it kinda pretends to behave as the score is described to behave, if you don't actually check it up: take the current score $x_n$, then pretend to compute $\frac{11}{10}(x_n +10)$ somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x_{n+1}=\frac{11}{10}(x_{n}+10)$

Then $x_{n+2}=\frac{11}{10}(\frac{11}{10}(x_{n}+10))+11=(\frac{11}{10})^2x_{n}+\frac{11^2}{10}+11$

You can continue this for the general form:
$$x_n=\bigg(\frac{11}{10}\bigg)^nx_0+\frac{11^{n+1}}{10^n}+\frac{11^n}{10^{n-1}}+\cdots+\frac{11^2}{10}+11$$

Since $x_0=0$, we are only interested in the other part of the series, which we can summarize as:
$$x_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{\frac{11^{r+1}}{10^r}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The future value of an annuity problem.

$FV = (Payment) + (Payment)(1+r) + (Payment)(1+r)^2 +\cdots+(Payment)(1+r)^n =  (Payment) \frac {(1+r)^{n+1}-1}{r}$